# Stripping html tags, 'RegExp-free-way'

Tags: javascript, html, html-sanitizing

I've got a bit paranoid lately about the solutions out there that deal with the task by using regular expressions to 'sanitize' html strings. They largely depend on how 'bullet-proof' given regex is. So, I came up with this snippet and hope to get some feedback about it from community. Thanks.

```
//
// #notags
String.prototype.notags = (function (doc) {

  var mkel     = doc.createElement.bind(doc);
  var hasown   = Function.prototype.call.bind(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty);

  // #textlike-nodes
  var textlike = {

    12 : "NOTATION_NODE", 
    3  : "TEXT_NODE", 
    4  : "CDATA_SECTION_NODE", 
    5  : "ENTITY_REFERENCE_NODE", 
    6  : "ENTITY_NODE", 
    7  : "PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE", 
    8  : "COMMENT_NODE"

  };

  // #_notags
  // main function
  var _notags = function (tagedstring) {

    var div;
    var istxt = istextnode;
    var nodes;
    var nodetxt = getxt;
    var res;

    div = mkel('div');
    div.innerHTML = (''+ tagedstring);


    // get the div's descendants 
    // and read their text content 
    // until all of its childern are plain 
    // text nodes...

    nodes = descendants(div);

    while (!nodes.every(istxt)) {
      div.innerHTML = nodetxt(div);
      nodes = descendants(div);
    }

    res = div.innerHTML;

    // get rid of temporary div
    // prevents mem. leaks
    div.innerHTML = '';
    delete div;

    return res;
  };


  // #save
  // String#notags
  return function () {
    return _notags(this);
  };



  ////////////////
  ////// #helpers

  // #istextnode
  function istextnode (node) {
    return !(3 - node.nodeType);
  }

  // #descendants
  function descendants (startnode, _nodels) {

    _nodels || (_nodels = []);

    var node = startnode.firstChild;

    while (node) {

      _nodels.push(node);
      descendants(node, _nodels);

      node = node.nextSibling;
    }

    return _nodels;
  }

  // #getxt
  // loop each node's descendant 
  // and fetch it' text content
  function getxt (node) {

    var _ = {
      str: '', 
      txt: textlike
    };

    descendants(node)
    .forEach(getnodetext, _);

    return _.str;
  }

  // #getnodetext
  function getnodetext (node) {
    //this: {str, txt}
    if (hasown(this.txt, node.nodeType))
      this.str += (node.data || node.textContent || node.nodeValue);
  }


})(document);

// /eof
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic; it **may** be appropriate to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: should I transfer it there? it's not a bunch of code...

Comment: Just sanitize your input on the server. It's something you'll have to do anyway so there really aren't any benefits to doing it on the client.

Comment: @Meredith, that's fine, but did I've asked should I do that or not?

Comment: @nikolav: I knew I was missing something (re the bind trick), very cool, I'm not sure I've seen that used before. And it even works on IE8 (with a `Function#bind` shim). Nifty!

Comment: ... yep, it's usefull one. I've seen people using it here and there, usually doing something like: `var corcall = Function.prototype.call;`, or `var corapply = Function.prototype.apply;` and building helper functions by binding native functions using that variables. For example: `var add = corapply.bind(Array.prototype.push)`, or, this one is 'popular': `var slice = corcall.bind(Array.prototype.slice);`, or 'quick-trim':
`var trim = corapply.bind(String.prototype.trim);`, etc...

Comment: also, I saw this one 1000 times: `var _string = corcall.bind(Object.prototype.toString);`...

Comment: this one is a 'killer' also: `var $ = (function (selector) {
  return this.slice(this.qsa.apply(null, arguments), 0);
}).bind(
{
  qsa: document.querySelectorAll.bind(document), 
  slice: Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice)
});`